# How can update data from datagridview to database with stored procedure?

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures, datagridview

I can not update data from datagridview to database by using stored procedure,
I am using the code below and it keeps on saying "BookID" column cannot be found,
The code i use is:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow datagridview in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", datagridview.Cells["BookID"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeneralID", datagridview.Cells["GeneralID"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorName", datagridview.Cells["AuthorName"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", datagridview.Cells["ISBN"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", datagridview.Cells["Title"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", datagridview.Cells["Genre"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Series", datagridview.Cells["Series"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfPublication", datagridview.Cells["YearOfPublication"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Thumbnail", image));


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", datagridview.Cells["Description"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", datagridview.Cells["FileName"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", datagridview.Cells["FileSize"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", datagridview.Cells["DateAdded"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MediaLength", datagridview.Cells["MediaLength"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MediaType", datagridview.Cells["MediaType"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MediaSubType", datagridview.Cells["MediaSubType"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAcquired", datagridview.Cells["DateAcquired"].Value);
                connect.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Does the table you want to update have the column `BookID`?

Comment: Double check the name of your `BookID` column of `DataGridView` control.

Comment: Check your storedprocedure using same name BookID

Comment: Are there more code before opening `{` inside `foreach` like `Using`? I assume also that your `CommandType` is `CommandType.StoredProcedure`?

Comment: Additionally is `BookID` `Auto Generated` or `AutoIncrement` type? Hope you have some `Try...Catch` just to check if there are errors on this one.